# What is the meaning of upward and downward arrows on double note in guitar tab?

Tags: guitar, notation, tablature

It is a part of Desperado song guitar tab. I'm wondering what does upward and downward arrows mean in the guitar tab?

[image]

Comment: Which version is this from? Can't remember a triplet feel in Desperado.

Comment: @Tim I've found it on [youtube](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=xywiN34xCzI)

Comment: It seems worth noting, that, though this definitely *means* upstroke/downstroke, the actual technique shown in the video doesn't do that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The arrows show the direction of strum, either up or down. I find it a  little strange, though, as with a triplet pattern, I'd use down, up, down, followed by the second beat of up, down, up, to keep the strumming hand/arm in rhythm, which isn't shown in this version.

Comment: I believe the down/up is reversed, based on the string direction of the tab. Also, only first 2 of 3 triplets are being played.

Comment: @JohnBelzaguy - what I meant was playing as writ, the strumming hand would stutter, and not be as easy to keep in time as if there was a ghost strum on the 3rd triplets (which I just don't hear in Desperado).

Comment: Off the top of my head I don’t recall any triplets in the song either. It also doesn’t specify, Eagles or Linda version, both are very well known. I get your point but considering the slow tempo I would personally be inclined to do down-up to keep the consistency between beats. Either way would work fine, after all it’s only a 2 note strum.

Comment: @JohnBelzaguy - turns out it's a red ferret - another Desperado..!

Answer (score 3):

It means upstroke and downstroke. It wants you to mimic strumming the two notes. The flamenco feeling loves strumming anything from 2 to 6 notes at a time. It is very stylistically accurate.